# VirtualBox Windows 8.1 Install Error - Failed To Install ntcreatesection monitor

Tags: installation, windows-8.1, virtualbox

> tl;dr - VirtualBox v4.3.13 has defects on Windows 8.1, revert to VirtualBox v4.3.12

Hi all,

This is a self answer, but I couldn't find a solution on here and wanted to make sure a solution to this problem is readily available. It sure made me angry...

I went to install VirtualBox Linux VM version 4.3.13 on my Windows 8.1 machine. The install appears to work fine until you try and launch the application. A critical error appears displaying the following...

> failed to install ntcreatesection monitor [random hex-byte values]

Annoying after completing the install completely with no errors/warnings...

Anyways, I found the solution and luckily it's pretty simple. The latest version (4.3.13) of VirtualBox has defects on Windows 8.1, reverting to version 4.3.12 works great on Windows 8.1.

This link (where I found the solution) describes in more detail...

https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/13187

Hopefully this saves a few people some trouble!

Comment: Same issue with VirtualBox v4.3.14 and VirtualBox v4.3.15. Rollback to 4.3.12.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after I have installed an antivirus software. Either disable antivirus program, if you have one, or go to settings in antivirus and allow *virtualbox.exe* to run.